# I am trying to do simple animation in css but am getting stuck?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation

So I am trying to animate a css div with **top property** not being there in the original div style because I want to delay the animation so I put it in the the **@keyframes** property but it disappears after the animation.

This is the css of the div

```
.MainTitle {
  left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 90px;
  animation: Othertitle 1s 800ms;
}
```

This is the animation

```
@keyframes Othertitle {
  from {
    top: 10%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 5%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML as well

```
<div className="MainTitle">
        <p>About</p>
</div>
```

it runs fine but then dissapears to the bottom of the page. How to make it stay?

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ed0jIOusvprHuhK0lXA5PLpyfd8x4jOT/view?usp=sharing) to see the problem.

Comment: You need to paste the HTML as well

Comment: @Tushar Added the HTML

Comment: As indicated in an answer the white text makes it invisible, but otherwise I don't see _text disappearing to the bottom_ of the page. As a separate note, I'd suggest you consider animating with `transform: translateY()` rather than with `top:` property. `position: absolute;` and `top:` properties are not meant for a general animation and might cause unintended side effects, aside from leading to poor performance.

Comment: [See the Problem Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ed0jIOusvprHuhK0lXA5PLpyfd8x4jOT/view?usp=sharing) @BumhanYu

Answer (score 1):

```css
@keyframes Othertitle {
  from {
    top: 10%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: 5%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.MainTitle {
  position:absolute;
  left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Londrina Solid', cursive;
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 90px;
  animation: Othertitle 1s 800ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="MainTitle">
        <p>About</p>
</div>
```

The only two problems:

## `className` is a attribute?

When I tested it in the snippet, the title did not do anything because `className` should actually be `class`.

## The color is white?

How can you see a white text in a white background? I think you meant `background-color`.

Comment: Its is className becasue its is react component. background color is black

Comment: thanks for helping me understand it because i dont really know react i only know regular html and css

Comment: Actually it works fine for me?